# Django rendering correct view but incorrect URL

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a video sharing application. On my video page, I have allowed users to post comments and to delete comments.

```
def video_content(request, video_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=video_id)
    ....
    return render(
        request,
        'video-content.html',
        context={
            'video': video,
        }
    )
```

I'm obviously omitting a lot of things in the code.

I also have a comment handler function

```
def add_comment(request, video_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=video_id)

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Get comment and save it

    return HttpResponse()
```

On my video page, I have a form:

```
<form action="/comment/add/{{video.id}}" method="post">
    <input type="text"></input>
    <button type="submit">Comment</button>
</form>
```

All of this works fine. When the user inputs a comment and submits the form, the `add_comment` function is successfully called just like its supposed to, and the comment is saved. The video page does not reload, which is what I want, but the URL on the top bar changes. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: this `return HttpResponse()` returns none view

Comment: Please show your URL patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do, is redirect the user to the view that you want.

```
def add_comment(request, video_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=video_id)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Get comment and save it
        return redirect("video_content",video.id)


    # return HttpResponse() # this, is not correct
    return render(request,"template_name.html",{})
```